# How to IDW interpolation in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

I'm trying to find PostGIS Raster functions supports the Inverse Distance Weighted interpolation method (IDW) and Kriging interpolation method. 
I'm especially trying to generate a temperature map from a geometry table with point locations in PostGIS.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Take a look at [ST_InvDistWeight4ma](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_InvDistWeight4ma.html) (I've never used it, so someone might need to elaborate)

Comment: You will need to use that function in conjunction with ST_MapAlgebra.